# What does "solapable" means?

Tags: definiciones

I can't find English explanation of this Spanish word, so please if you can help me? Its about electronics. Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe it refers to "solapar" --> http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=solapar Try to provide more context.

Comment: Try with _overlapping_.

Comment: What research have you done? Have you consulted a dictionary? If so, please indicate this in your question, and explain why you're having trouble finding the definition.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a general reference question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means it **overlaps** (`solapar` = **overlap**). A website for example, may have overlap menus (`Un menú solapable, o que se solapa`), and some roofs use an overlap technique (`El techo está formado por tejas solapadas`).

Answer (score 1):

Something "solapable" is something you can place over another thing and easily remove it, it's not very used and quite hard to explain, could you provide an example please?